# How to read specific lines from a single file and write in a same line in new file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

```
import os
post_analysis_log = open("Complete_post_analysis.text",'w')

directory='/media/quinn/Joker/Anaysis/KCATBH00'

for x in range (1,6):
    os.chdir(directory +str(x)+'/')
    print(os.getcwd())
    with open ('post_analysis.log','r') as post:
        lines=post.readlines()

post_analysis_log.write("KCATBH00")
post_analysis_log.write(str(x))
post_analysis_log.write("    ")
post_analysis_log.write(lines[1])
post_analysis_log.write("    ")
post_analysis_log.write(lines[3])
```

Here is the code i am using it to write in a single line, but unfortuntely it's writing in the another line.

Comment: Your code is badly indented - please fix by [edit]ing.

Comment: if you read the documentation of readlines() you would be able to see that it does not remove lineending . you need to do that yourself:  `post_analysis_log.write(lines[1].strip())` to avoind inserting a line with a newline inside.

Comment: indention wasn't a problem there, but strip is like half of working. Thanks for your help !! now I have to remove the alphabets and write only integer value. Now this going to be a problem so as I am new to python.

Comment: Identation of the code you _posted_ is a problem. if I try to run you code I get errors `with open ('post_analysis.log','r') as post:` has no indented code blocks wich it needs.#

Comment: yes in the shown code there was not proper indentation. My BAD!!

Comment: Fixed missing indentation of `with` body